# Importing std_msgs.msg with Python

Tags: ros-melodic, rospy

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi guys, I am following the ROS Beginner's Tutorials, on the part Writing a Simple Publisher and Subscriber (Python). In the publisher code given, there is a line which says from std_msgs.msg import String. From my knowledge of python, this means that std_msgs.msg is a module name (i.e. a .py file) and there should be a class definition for String inside that file. However, I can't seem to find this file (i.e. I can't find any file named std_msgs.msg.py). I looked through the documentation and it says that rospy do create python source code for msg files, so there must be this std_msgs.msg.py file somewhere. Anyone knows where this file is located? Or perhaps my understanding is wrong?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/331593/importing-std_msgs.msg-with-python/) by [Ricky98](https://answers.ros.org/users/45172/ricky98/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2019-08-26

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> From my knowledge of python, this means that std_msgs.msg is a module name (i.e. a .py file) and there should be a class definition for String inside that file.
>
> [..]
>
> I looked through the documentation and it says that rospy do create python source code for msg files, so there must be this std_msgs.msg.py file somewhere [..]

While it is true that Python modules are contained in a single file (ie: one with the same name as the module + `.py`), there is a second construct called a *package* that is what is used here in this case.

Any directory with a `__init__.py` file in it will be considered a package by the Python interpreter. Any files inside that directory (apart from `__init__.py`) are again modules (which can contain classes and other Python entities), and sub directories of a package's directory will be considered sub packages (as long as they also contain a `__init__.py` file).

In the case of `std_msgs`, this is what that looks like:

```
└── /opt/ros/kinetic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
  └── std_msgs
    ├── __init__.py
    └── msg
      ├── _Bool.py
      ├── _ByteMultiArray.py
      ├── _Byte.py
      ├── ..
      ├── __init__.py
      ├── ..
      ├── _String.py
      ├── ..
      ├── _UInt8MultiArray.py
      └── _UInt8.py
```

So all ROS Python (2) packages (note: not necessarily ROS packages, as a single ROS package may contain multiple Python packages) are located in `/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages`, in which there is a sub directory called `std_msgs`. This contains a `__init__.py` file, marking it as a sub package. This has a sub directory `msg`, which then contains both a `__init__.py` as well as all the files that contain the implementations of all the message classes (and which were generated by `genpy` (not `rospy`).

When you write `from std_msgs.msg import String`, the Python interpreter will traverse this directory structure and end up at `_String.py`, load it and make all the contained symbols available to the session.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2019-08-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) on 2019-08-26**:
I'd absolutely support this explanation, if there wouldn't be this distinction in the [Python docs](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html):

> A module is a file containing Python definitions and statements.

and

> Packages are a way of structuring Python’s module namespace by using “dotted module names”.

Though this distinction is kind of strange/unintuitive in my perspective. And as far as I have seen you are absolutely fine going with this explanation.

**Comment by [Ricky98](https://answers.ros.org/users/45172/ricky98/) on 2019-08-26**:
Oh wow, I didn't even know about python packages and importing them, since I just learned python a week ago. Thank you so much for clarifying the whole thing. The link posted by mgruhler was very helpful too.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-08-26**:
@mgruhler: you're correct, and I've updated the answer.

**Comment by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) on 2019-08-26**:
The answer by @gvdhoorn is way more self-contained now, so I suggest to mark this as the correct one.

**Comment by [Michdo93](https://answers.ros.org/users/39516/michdo93/) on 2021-06-29**:
If you have installed and build ROS from source the path is as example `~/ros_catkin_ws/install_isolated/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/` instead of `/opt/ros/$ROSDISTRO/lib/python2.7/dist-packages`

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Not quite correct.

`String` is the module, which is located in the `std_msgs.msg` (sub-)package. So you would need to be looking for a `String.py` file (or to be correct in this case, `_String.py`). The full path to the file, if installed via apt, is `/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/std_msgs/msg/_String.py`.

See also [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7948494/whats-the-difference-between-a-python-module-and-a-python-package) or [this explanation of Python Packages](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/package).

---

Originally posted by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) with karma: 12390 on 2019-08-26

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2